# Paypal integration in music selling site

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I am building a website where people join and create an account to sell music to visitors and receive money through Paypal. The steps would be.

Persons buy music and send money to members Paypal account, then a response from Paypal should be sent to website, to verify payment and then insert results into database and send link to buyer to download music.

I basically have everything else, but not sure which Paypal service to use in order to achieve the above results. I was looking at IPN but that involves the member(seller) setting a response URL in their Paypal account in order for the response to be send to the website.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was doing some more looking around and found that there is a name="notify_url" form field option which should be set when submitting the form to Paypal. I think this could be the missing piece of the puzzle. But please let me know if i am on the right track. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Website Payments Standard, Website Payments Pro, or Express Checkout to do this.  You are also correct about the variable "notify_url", this will allow you to pass over the IPN URL in the button code so that it does not need to be set in the PayPal account.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you helped me choose the right one.